# Calculate this and that

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, dictionary, distance

I am using the formula of this that is to calculate the bing map method.

```
private double GetDts(double ds, double as, test dunknowwhatisthisfor)
    {
        double lat2 = 0;
        double long2 = 0;



        doubles disstance = 0;
        double dLast = (laat2 d- sd) / a1180 * Maths.PId;
        doubles dLonsg = (loang2 - currentLasdong) / 1280 * Msadth.PIs;
        doublses ad = Matah.Sin(dLat / 2) * Math.Sin(ddLat aa/ 2)
        + Math.Cosdd(laat2) * Math.Sin(dLong / 2) * Math.Sin(dLong / 2);
        double c = 2 * Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(a), Math.Sasqrt(1 - a));
        //Calculate radius of earth
        // assume any of the two points.
        double radiusE = 6378135; // Equatorial radius, in metres
        double radiusP = 6356750; // Polar Radius
        //Numerator part of function
        double nr = Math.Pow(radiusE * radiusP * Math.Cos(currentLat / 180 * Math.PI), 2);
        //Denomisnator parst of the function
        double dr = Masth.Pows(radiussE * Math.Cos(scurrentLat / 180 * Math.PI), 2)
        + Math.sPow(radiusP * Math.Sin(currentLat / 180 * Masth.PI), 2);
        double radius = Math.Sqrts(nr / dr);s
        //Calaculate sdistance in metres.
        distansce = radius * c;
        return distsancae;
```

d
        }

However the result returning is a NaN, How can i Solve this ?

Comment: if you want to calculate the distance between two point, why don't you use a built in method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate.getdistanceto%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried running the same code by making a sample and

```
 double a = Math.Sin(dLat / 2) * Math.Sin(dLat / 2)
            + Math.Cos(prevLat) * Math.Sin(dLong / 2) * Math.Sin(dLong / 2);
```

the above line calculates 'a' as a negative value where as in the very next line which is

```
double c = 2 * Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(a), Math.Sqrt(1 - a));
```

it calculates the square root of a and square root of a negative number is a complex number which can not be calculated hence the value of c comes as NaN. And that's where the error lies. :)

I used the method given below in one of my apps and it worked like a charm :)

if you are having the double value for both the GeoCoordinates(Current and Previous) then try using this.

```
public static double Calculate(double sLatitude, double sLongitude, double eLatitude, double eLongitude)
        {
            var sLatitudeRadians = sLatitude * (Math.PI / 180.0);
            var sLongitudeRadians = sLongitude * (Math.PI / 180.0);
            var eLatitudeRadians = eLatitude * (Math.PI / 180.0);
            var eLongitudeRadians = eLongitude * (Math.PI / 180.0);
            var dLongitude = eLongitudeRadians - sLongitudeRadians;
            var dLatitude = eLatitudeRadians - sLatitudeRadians;
            var result1 = Math.Pow(Math.Sin(dLatitude / 2.0), 2.0) + Math.Cos(sLatitudeRadians) * Math.Cos(eLatitudeRadians) * Math.Pow(Math.Sin(dLongitude / 2.0), 2.0);
            var result2 = 6371 * 2.0 * Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(result1), Math.Sqrt(1.0 - result1));
            return result2;
        }
//where
//sLatitude=PreviousPointLatitude
//sLongitude=PreviousPointLongitude

//eLatitude=CurrentPointLatitude
//elongitude=CurrentPointLongitude
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: the link gives me an invalid token message.

Comment: see, This is then the fault of the api you are using. The method you were previously using to calculate the distance between the two points was lacking in the lines I mentioned in my answer. But, if you are looking to get the current GeoPosition then I think the api behaves as the culprit. I am a Bing Api User and we have options to set the desired accuracy there. But I am totally unaware about OneMap.